# How to pass operators as parameters

Tags: c++

I have to load an array of `doubles` from a file, multiply each element by a value in a table (different values for different elements), do some work on it, invert the multiplication (that is, divide) and then save the data back to file.

Currently I implement the multiplication and division process in two separate methods. Now there is some extra work behind the scenes but apart from the specific statements where the multiplication/division occurs, the rest of the code is identical. As you can imagine, with this approach you have to be very careful making any changes. The surrounding code is not trivial, so its either a case of manually editing each method or copying changes from one method to the other and remembering to change the * and / operators.

After too many close calls I am fed up of this and would like to make a common function which implements the common logic and two wrapper functions which pass which operator to use as a parameter.

My initial approach was to use function pointers:

```
void MultiplyData(double data)  
{ TransformData(data, &(operator *));  } 

void DivideData(double data)  
{ TransformData(data, &(operator /));  }  

void TransformData(double data, double (*func)(double op1, double op2))  
{  /* Do stuff here... */ }
```

However, I can't pass the operators as pointers (is this because it is an operator on a native type?), so I tried to use function objects. Initially I thought that `multiplies` and `divides` functors in `<functional>` would be ideal:

```
void MultiplyData(double data)  
{  
    std::multiplies<double> multFunct;  
    TransformData(data, &multFunct);  
}

void DivideData(double data)  
{  
    std::divides<double> divFunct;  
    TransformData(data, &divFunct);  
}

void TransformData(double data, std::binary_function<double, double, double> *funct)  
{  /* Do stuff here... */ }
```

As you can see I was trying to use a base class pointer to pass the functor polymorphically. The problem is that `std::binary_function` does not declare an `operator()` member for the child classes to implement.

Is there something I am missing, or is the solution to implement my own functor heirarchy (which really seems more trouble than it is worth)?

Comment: `TransformData` is my own function which transforms `data` using the function pointed to by `funct`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make TransformData a template function:

```
template <typename F>
typename F::result_type TransformData(double data, F f) { ... }
```

Call it thus:

```
double MultiplyData(double data) {
    return TransformData(data, std::multiplies<double>());
}
```

std::binary_function is a tagging class. It's primary purpose is not to provide a base class interface, but to inject some typedefs into functor-style classes (via inheritance), which makes them usable by other parts of the standard library.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking :)

Comment: Your functions and function templates need return types.

Comment: @Charles: as (I'd guess) you're already aware, that's exactly what `binary_function` provides -- typedefs for the types of the parameters and the return.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: I meant at a more basic level: `MultiplyData(double data) { ... }` isn't valid in C++, it needs to be `void MultiplyData(double data) { ... }` or whatever the return type actually should be.

Comment: @Charles: right -- it's the latter case the `binary_function` helps with (i.e. determining what the return type actually should be).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Charles; I was being lazy. I've added them in now.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at using Boost.Bind or Boost.Function so that you can do something like this:

```
TransformData(boost::function<double(double, double)> func) {
  // use func like a function that 
  // returns a double and takes two 
  // double parameters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a more generic solution, but in this case I'd use the fact that division is the same as multiplication by the inverse, i.e. `x/C` == `x * (1/C)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: TransformData should be template function that uses static polymorphism rather then dynamic. `binary_function` is only "tag", these multiples and divides do not overload its `operator()` - because it does not have one.

```
template<typename Func>
void TransformData(double *data,Func f)
{
   for(int i=0;i<some_data_size;i++)
      data[i]=f(data[i],otherdata[i]);
}
```

And now f would be used correctly. multiples, divides or any other.

And then you call

```
TransformData(data,std::multiples<double>());
TransformData(data,std::divides<double>());
TransformData(data,some_other_functional);
```

Comment: `binary_function` does not have an `operator()`, at least in the VC++ implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider using `std::transform` instead of your `TransformData`. As you've written it, `TransformData` requires tighter coupling (inheritance) than is really necessary in this case. If you use inheritance, it means your multiply and divide functions would have to be virtual, which (in the case of something as simple as multiplication or division) would probably add significant overhead.

`std::transform` doesn't require a virtual function call. With it, the function to be invoked is a template parameter, which means as long as whatever you pass supports the normal *syntax* for a function call (i.e. putting parentheses after the name) it'll work.

Since `transform` also uses iterators, you can apply it directly to the input as you read from the file:

```
transform(istream_iterator<double>(infile),
          istream_iterator<double>(),
          coefficients.begin(),
          data.begin(), 
          std::multiply);

// do the other work on data

transform(data.begin(), 
          data.end(), 
          coefficients.begin(), 
          ostream_iterator<double>(outfile),
          std::divide);
```

Another possibility to consider would be to use `std::valarray`s instead. With an `valarray`, the code could be as simple as: `data *= coefficients;` and `data /= coefficients;`

Comment: I did consider using `transform` but the multplication/division is  part of a more complex function where the application of the input function is determined by the output of the previous transforms, that is, the individual transforms are not independent of each other. Sorry, I should have made this clear instead of just hinting at the "more complex" nature of the function.

Still, it is an interesting approach that I would take further if it didn't require implementing a stateful functor to work.

Answer (score 0):

As Marcelo suggested, except that I would not pass the function object as a parameter, but construct internally as:

```
template <typename TransformationFunctor>
TransformData(double data) 
{  
    TransformationFunctor f;
    ...
}
```

and then use as:

```
MultiplyData(double data)
{ 
    TransformData< std::multiplies<double> >(data); 
}
```

Comment: What are the benefits to this approach over Marcelo's?

Comment: I do not think this is very different from Marcelo's suggestion, and either would work fine. I prefer this approach as it reduces the number of run-time arguments being passed into the function, saves the "()" to construct an anonymous temporary object, and a pass by value of the object(copy construction). But for a trivial TranformationFunctor, these should not matter anyway. Generally though, keeping the number of run-time arguments to the minimum is a  good thing as when the function is pushed onto the stack the arguments may be placed in registers.

Comment: Oh but there is a draw back, you can not "pass-in" function objects with "state", so I think Marcelo's implementation is better.